# "can't assign to property "validator" on "formControlAnimalSelect": not an object" Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to apply a validator when without filling a select, but I'm getting

> "can't assign to property "validator" on "formControlAnimalSelect":
>   not an object"

I try:

**TS:**

```
  formControlAnimalSelect = new FormControl('valid', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('valid'),
    ])

ngOnInit() {
      this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        formControlAnimalSelect:['',Validators.required]
      });
```

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
<div class="formSegundoGrupo">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select name="selectAnimals" formControl="formControlAnimalSelect" placeholder="Eu perdi um...">
                    <mat-option value="gato">
                      Gato
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="cahorro">
                      Cachorro
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="coelho">
                      Coelho
                    </mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="tartaruga">
                      Tartaruga
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>

                  <mat-error *ngIf="selectAnimal.hasError('required')">Você precisa selecionar ao menos um pet!</mat-error>

                </mat-form-field>
              </div>

             </form>
```

Comment: Replace `formControl="formControlAnimalSelect"` by `formControlName="formControlAnimalSelect"`. It's also unclear why you create a `new FormControl('valid' ...)` if you don't use it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you had implemented the one thing in two different way.

> Case 1 : If you want to use use only control

#### ts

```
  formControlAnimalSelect = new FormControl('valid', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('valid'),
    ])

ngOnInit() {
      /* Remove this code
      this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        formControlAnimalSelect:['',Validators.required]
      });*/
  }
```

#### html

```
<mat-select name="selectAnimals" 
 [formControl]="formControlAnimalSelect" placeholder="Eu perdi um...">
```

> Case 2 : If you want to use the control along with form

#### ts

```
 /* remove this code
 formControlAnimalSelect = new FormControl('valid', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('valid'),
    ])
 */

ngOnInit() {
      this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        formControlAnimalSelect:['',Validators.required]
      });
```

#### html

```
<mat-select name="selectAnimals" 
 formControlName="formControlAnimalSelect" placeholder="Eu perdi um...">
```

Comment: when i try to show a error: "<mat-error *ngIf="formControlAnimalSelect.hasError('required')">You must make a selection</mat-error>"

i receive:

ERROR TypeError: "_co.formControlAnimalSelect is undefined"

Comment: use `secondFormGroup.get('formControlAnimalSelect').hasError('required')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `formControlName` directive instead of `formControl`.

```
formControlName="formControlAnimalSelect"
```

I'm not sure why you defined `formControlAnimalSelect` at the begining :( Actually since you need it to be part of formGroup `secondFormGroup`, you can easily change `formControl` initialization like below.

```
this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    formControlAnimalSelect: new FormControl('valid', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('valid'),
   ])
});
```

For error handling you can use

```
*ngIf="secondFormGroup.get('formControlAnimalSelect').hasError('required')"
```

Comment: ok, but if i try to apply a has error:

"<mat-error *ngIf="formControlAnimalSelect.hasError('pattern') && !formControlAnimalSelect.hasError('required')">
                      Your selection is invalid
</mat-error>

I receive ERROR TypeError: "_co.formControlAnimalSelect is undefined"

Comment: change expression to `secondFormGroup.get('formControlAnimalSelect').hasError('required')`

Answer (score 0):

For me this is what i had, and it was giving me the same error:

```
<form formGroup="productCreateForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

Changed it to this and it worked:

```
<form [formGroup]="productCreateForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```