# ERROR TypeError: "can't assign to property "validator" on "signUpForm": not an object"

Tags: angular, html, typescript

ERROR TypeError: "can't assign to property "validator" on "sign Up Form": not an object"

I tried all the solution answered in the same question but didn't work.
["can't assign to property "validator" on "formControlAnimalSelect": not an object" Angular Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239335/cant-assign-to-property-validator-on-formcontrolanimalselect-not-an-objec)

I also checked the link between the FormGroup in my TypeScript code and the form element in my HTML, it's correct.

```
 //typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
  import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
  import {Router} from '@angular/router';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  signUpForm: FormGroup;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm() {
    this.signUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern
      (/[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}/)]]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const email = this.signUpForm.get('email').value;
    const password = this.signUpForm.get('password').value;
    this.authService.createNewUser(email, password).then(
      () => {
        this.router.navigate(['/books']);
      },
    (error) => {
      this.errorMessage = error;
    }

    );
  }


}
```

```
<html>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <h2>Create an account</h2>
    <form formGroup="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email"> Email </label>
        <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control"
               formControlName="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password"> Password </label>
        <input type="password" id="password"
               class="form-control" formControlName="password">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
              [disabled]="signUpForm.invalid"> Create account</button>
    </form>
    <p class="text-danger">{{errorMessage}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML should look like

try this:

```
<html>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <h2>Create an account</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email"> Email </label>
        <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control"
               formControlName="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password"> Password </label>
        <input type="password" id="password"
               class="form-control" formControlName="password">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
              [disabled]="signUpForm.invalid"> Create account</button>
    </form>
    <p class="text-danger">{{errorMessage}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to missed bind `FormGroup` that why error is occurs if you have to add this your code is good.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <h2>Create an account</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email"> Email </label>
        <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control"
               formControlName="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password"> Password </label>
        <input type="password" id="password"
               class="form-control" formControlName="password">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
              [disabled]="signUpForm.invalid"> Create account</button>
    </form>
    <p class="text-danger">{{errorMessage}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also check on the link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-buks6o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @YoussefKhedher its pleasure to help you:)